# What's it called when person A's shoulders are in person B's shoulders in a reassuring way, and B's hands are on top of person A's hands?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, etymology, phrases

What's it called when person A's shoulders are in person B's shoulders in a reassuring way, and B's hands are on top of person A's hands? If there's not a word please help me describe it in a clear sentence.

It's super hard to explain which is why I'm having trouble with it. It's kind of like the photo below, but the people are facing each other.

[image]

Comment: Person's A shoulders *are in* Person's B shoulders??

Comment: I don't think the action moves far beyond simply saying A was placing hands on B's shoulders in a(n) ___ way. Words like comforting, reassuring and understanding can capture a large amount of information about *how* A touched B, without explicitly describing the physical interaction.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a common enough gesture to have a name of its own. You would have to describe what happened - for example

> A laid his hands reassuringly on B's shoulders. "......", he said.

> B reached up and placed his hands over A's.